# how to print track data (swift)

Tags: ios, json, swift

So I have the following code printing out the following

```
[DRN1.Data(track: DRN1.Trackinfo(title: "Charly\'s Ballad (Original Mix)", artist: "Castle Queenside", imageurl: "covers.drn1.com.au/az_B1017197_Disc 1 Traxsource Nu Disco & Indie Dance_Castle Queenside.jpg"))]
```

However when I go to write

```
print(nowplaying.data.track.title)
```

I get errors and it won't even attempt to load the swift app

```
struct Nowplayng: Decodable{
    let data: [Data]
}

struct Data: Decodable{
    let track: Trackinfo
}
struct Trackinfo: Decodable {
    let title: String
    let artist: String
    let imageurl: String
}
```

**works**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        let jsonURLString = "https://api.drn1.com.au/station/playing"
        guard let feedurl = URL(string: jsonURLString) else { return }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: feedurl) { (data,response,err)
            in

            guard let data = data else { return }

            do{
                let nowplaying = try JSONDecoder().decode(Nowplayng.self, from: data)
                    print(nowplaying.data)


            }catch let jsonErr{
            print("error json ", jsonErr)
            }

//            let dataAsString = String(data:data, encoding: .utf8)
//            print(dataAsString)
        }.resume()



    }
```

**does not work**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        let jsonURLString = "https://api.drn1.com.au/station/playing"
        guard let feedurl = URL(string: jsonURLString) else { return }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: feedurl) { (data,response,err)
            in

            guard let data = data else { return }

            do{
                let nowplaying = try JSONDecoder().decode(Nowplayng.self, from: data)
                    print(nowplaying.data.track.title)


            }catch let jsonErr{
            print("error json ", jsonErr)
            }

//            let dataAsString = String(data:data, encoding: .utf8)
//            print(dataAsString)
        }.resume()



    }
```

Comment: `Data` is an existing Swift type, so don't define your own type using the same name.  At best it will be confusing, at worst it could break the compilation.

Comment: In fact I can't see any point in having the interim Data type, unless it is to mirror JSON for decoding purposes (and even then it would be easy to flatten it away).  Then you could just do struct Nowplayng: Decodable{
    let playingTracks: [Trackinfo]
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data` is an array you need to loop over it

```
nowplaying.data.forEach {
   print($0.track.title)
}
```

---

If you care about the first item do

```
if let item = nowplaying.data.first {
   print(item.track.title)
}
```

Comment: So I always need to do it that way? even if it only returns 1 now playing info?